# Get a portion of the original image and put it onto another image using numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, numpy-ndarray, numpy-slicing

I have two pictures, 1 of a minion with green background and one of a cat. I want to get the minion from the first and image and put it in front of the cat in the 2nd page. I have written the code for this:

```
minion = Image.open('g.jpg')
newsize = (900, 800)

minion = np.array(minion.resize(newsize))
h = mpimg.imread('h.jpg')

minion=np.array(minion)

first=minion[1][1]
s=minion.shape

i=Image.open("h.jpg")
i =np.array( i.convert('RGB'))

a=i.shape[0]-minion.shape[0]
b=i.shape[1]//2.2
b = int(b)

for x in range(len(minion)):
  for y in range(len(minion[0])):
    if  np.all(minion[x][y]==first):
      continue

    i[a+x][b+y]=minion[x][y]


mpimg.imsave('i.jpg', i)
```

My output image is:

[image]

My only issue is that I can't seem to further reduce the green background that is left behind the minion. How do I reduce it I have tried setting first = minion[n][n] to different values but cannot reduce the green from this point onwards. Any guidance will be appreciated.

Separate Images:

[image: cat]

[image: minion]

Comment: provide a [mre]. that includes input data. **do not loop.** numpy indexing. use a mask (boolean array).  https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing

Comment: Please the images separately

Comment: Separate images added

Answer (score 0):

This is likely an artifact of JPEG compression. Either use high quality images with lossless formats like PNG, or use the concept of *threshold*. That is, instead of

```
minion[x][y] == first
```

use

```
np.sum(np.abs(minion[x][y] - first)) < thresh
```

and tune the value of `thresh` to get the desired effect. You can use more sophisticated functions for color distance, which is an entire topic of its own.

Finally, as @ChristophRackwitz noted, you can lose the loops and use numpy vectorized functions to improve runtime speed—if needed.

## Edit

This code only works if image data types are signed (so no unsigned underflow problem). So we need to add this before the loop:

```py
thresh = 200
minion = minion.astype(int)
first = first.astype(int)
```

And the final result would be:
[image]

Comment: Better take the absolute value before summing the components.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Good point! I've updated the answer,

Comment: I did this but setting thresh to different values obviously tweaks the amount of yellow and blue in the minion itself. I only wanted the green to be removed. I figured out a solution using cv2 but I am not allowed to used it, lol

Comment: I got it. Thanks.
One last additional suggestion from you, can this be done without using PIL?

Comment: PIL doesn't have a fundamental role here. Your code uses it to read JPEG files, but this can be done using other tools like matplotlib, etc.